# Strange behaviour when mixing abstractmethod, classmethod and property decorators

Tags: python, abstract-class, python-decorators

I've been trying to see whether one can create an abstract class property by mixing the three decorators (in Python 3.9.6, if that matters), and I noticed some strange behaviour.

Consider the following code:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Foo(ABC):
    @classmethod
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def x(cls):
        print(cls)
        return None

class Bar(Foo):
    @classmethod
    @property
    def x(cls):
        print("this is executed")
        return super().x
```

This outputs

```
this is executed
<class '__main__.Bar'>
```

This means that somehow, `Bar.x` ends up being called.

PyCharm warns me that `Property 'self' cannot be deleted`. If I reverse the order of `@classmethod` and `@property`, `Bar.x` is not called, but I still get the same warning, and also another one: `This decorator will not receive a callable it may expect; the built-in decorator returns a special object` (this also appears whenever I put `@property` above `@classmethod`).

Removing any of the three decorators (with the appropriate changes: adding `()` when removing `@property` or changing `cls` to `self` when removing `@classmethod`) also prevents `Bar.x` from being called.

I suppose all of this means that it's probably just a bad idea to directly mix those decorators (as indicated by discussion about class properties in other threads here).

Neverthless, I am curious: what is happening here? Why is Bar.x called?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve when you say a "class property"? You probably should not try to mix `property` and `classmethod`, instead, create your own custom descriptor. That would be much more sane.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Mixing `classmethod` and `property` like that is actually supported now - they changed how `classmethod` interacts with arbitrary descriptors.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica ahhh yes. I actually recall seeing this in the new and improved Descriptor HOWTO, basically it checks if the functions has a `__get__` and invokes it with the class.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica: The fact that this works without `@abstractmethod` made me think that is the case! Do you remember where this feature/change is documented? I'd like to see the details.

Comment: @tomasz: I'm not sure if there's any detailed documentation. All I have is this note in the [`classmethod` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod): "Changed in version 3.9: Class methods can now wrap other descriptors such as property()."

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica: Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the logic that checks for inherited abstract methods.

An object in a class dict is considered abstract if retrieving its `__isabstractmethod__` attribute produces `True`. When `Bar` subclasses `Foo`, Python needs to determine whether `Bar` overrides the abstract `Foo.x`, and if so, whether the override is itself abstract. It *should* do this by searching the MRO for an `'x'` entry in a class dict, so it can examine `__isabstractmethod__` on descriptors directly without invoking the descriptor protocol, but instead, it performs [a simple `Bar.x` attribute access](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.6/Modules/_abc.c#L379).

The `Bar.x` attribute access invokes the class property. It also returns `None` instead of the abstract property, and `None` isn't abstract, so Python gets confused about whether `Bar.x` is abstract. Python ends up still thinking `Bar.x` is abstract due to a different check, but if you change the example a bit:

```
>>> from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
>>> 
>>> class Foo(ABC):
...     @classmethod
...     @property
...     @abstractmethod
...     def x(cls):
...         print(cls)
...         return None
... 
>>> class Bar(Foo): pass
... 
<class '__main__.Bar'>
>>> Bar()
<__main__.Bar object at 0x7f46eca8ab80>
```

Python ends up thinking `Bar` is a concrete class, even though the changed example doesn't override `x` at all.

Comment: That is very clear and informative, thank you!

Comment: I submitted a bug report based on this thread: https://bugs.python.org/issue44904

Comment: @tomasz: My apologies, I misread the code in the original question. Yup, that's a bug! As you were.

Comment: (Specifically, I didn't notice that the property was "called" while the subclassing was taking place, despite no instance of the class ever having been created.)

Comment: @tomasz: ...Yes, I should have said "despite `Bar.x` never having been called on the class or an instance of the class". (I find the idea of calling a `classmethod` `property` on a class, rather than an instance of a class, a little mind-bending, I have to confess.)

Answer (score 3):

You can try raising an exception in `Bar.x`. This way you can see where it is called.

It should lead you to `abc.py` in the standard library, specifically the line [`_abc_init(cls)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/03648a2a91f9f1091cd21bd4cd6ca092ddb25640/Lib/abc.py#L107). This function is implemented in C. One of the first things this does is call [`compute_abstract_methods(self)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ca2009d72a52a98bf43aafa9ad270a4fcfabfc89/Modules/_abc.c#L299) checks all the abstract methods the class has inherited to see if they're implemented. This means getting `Bar.x` which invokes the property getter.