# Read-only class properties in python ≥3.9 with `help()` support

Tags: python-3.x, properties, metaclass, class-method, python-3.9

Since python 3.9, it is supported to stack the `@property` and `@classmethod` decorators. However, I struggle to create a class-property that shows up in `help` under the `Readonly properties` section. The solutions presented in [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203286/how-to-create-a-read-only-class-property-in-python/35640842),[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128573/using-property-on-classmethods),[[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189699/how-to-make-a-class-property?noredirect=1&lq=1),[[4]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273293/python-read-only-class-properties?noredirect=1&lq=1),[[5]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68763357/9318372) didn't solve my problem. Consider:

```py
from time import sleep
from abc import ABC, ABCMeta, abstractmethod

def compute(obj, s):
    print(f"Computing {s} of {obj} ...", end="")
    sleep(3)
    print("DONE!")
    return "Phew, that was a lot of work!"


class MyMetaClass(ABCMeta):
    @property
    def expensive_metaclass_property(cls):
        """This may take a while to compute!""" 
        return compute(cls, "metaclass property")

    
class MyBaseClass(ABC, metaclass=MyMetaClass):
    @classmethod
    @property
    def expensive_class_property(cls):
        """This may take a while to compute!"""
        return compute(cls, "class property")
    
    @property
    def expensive_instance_property(self):
        """This may take a while to compute!"""   
        return compute(self, "instance property")

class MyClass(MyBaseClass):
    """Some subclass of MyBaseClass"""
    
help(MyClass)
```

The issue is that calling `help(MyBaseClass)` executes `expensive_class_property` multiple times. This caused issues with documentation in the past where for example `sphinx` would also end up executing the property code.

Using the metaclass avoids this issue, but has the disadvantage that `expensive_metaclass_property` neither shows up in `dir(MyClass)` nor `help(MyClass)` nor in documentation of `MyClass`. How can I get a class-property that shows up in `help(MyClass)` under the `Readonly properties` section?

Here's what happens when calling `help(MyClass)`:

```
Computing class property of <class '__main__.MyClass'> ...DONE!
Computing class property of <class '__main__.MyClass'> ...DONE!
Computing class property of <class '__main__.MyClass'> ...DONE!
Computing class property of <class '__main__.MyBaseClass'> ...DONE!
Computing class property of <class '__main__.MyClass'> ...DONE!

Help on class MyClass in module __main__:

class MyClass(MyBaseClass)
 |  Some subclass of MyBaseClass
 |  
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      MyClass
 |      MyBaseClass
 |      abc.ABC
 |      builtins.object
 |  
 |  Data and other attributes defined here:
 |  
 |  __abstractmethods__ = frozenset()
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Class methods inherited from MyBaseClass:
 |  
 |  expensive_class_property = 'Phew, that was a lot of work!'
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Readonly properties inherited from MyBaseClass:
 |  
 |  expensive_instance_property
 |      This may take a while to compute!
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors inherited from MyBaseClass:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
```

Comment: Is it acceptable to cache the computed result? Or must it be recomputed on every invocation?

Comment: @wim I am already combining it with a cache decorator later on. However, that means it still gets executed at least once when it should get executed 0 times just like the `expensive_instance_property`.

Comment: OK so the main problem is not really the multiple invocations, but that autodoc invokes the property code at all?

Comment: Bug report from OP: https://bugs.python.org/issue45356

Answer (score 0):

Using the call stack, you can detect if the property was invoked by pydoc and short-circuit in that case:

```
import inspect

class A:
    @classmethod
    @property
    def expensive_class_property(cls):
        """This may take a while to compute!"""
        fnames = [f.filename for f in inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())]
        if any(fname.endswith("pydoc.py") for fname in fnames):
            return "Text returned for autodoc"
        print("computing class property")
        return "Phew, that was a lot of work!"
```

This help will look something like this:

```
Help on class A in module __main__:

class A(builtins.object)
 |  Class methods defined here:
 |  
 |  expensive_class_property = 'Text returned for autodoc'
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
```

But normal access will be as expected:

```
>>> A.expensive_class_property
computing class property
'Phew, that was a lot of work!'
```

It doesn't prevent `help(A)` from invoking the descriptor multiple times, but you may not be able to prevent this without modifying `pydoc.py` directly. As long as the short-circuit is fast, then you likely don't need to prevent it anyway.

This approach should be easily extensible to detect invocation by Sphinx. If you don't like adding the short-circuit code directly into the body of the function, this idea could be factored out to a decorator.